# What does "<top (required)>" mean in a Ruby stack trace?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby 1.9.2 stack trace I frequently see the method given as `<top (required)>`, as in this section of stack below.  What does this mean?  Is my Ruby install subtly broken?

```
Could not find abstract-1.0.0 in any of the sources
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `map!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/definition.rb:135:in `specs_for'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/definition.rb:124:in `requested_specs'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/setup.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `rescue in require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's the top level of a file i.e. whatever gets run when the file is required.
So if something fails during the setup of a library (for example some required file isn't found) it will show up in the stacktrace like that.

Comment: So the "(required)" part means that the file was processed because another file specified it with "require xxxxx", is that right?

Answer (score 2):

If everything you required is correct, it could mean that you're trying to create a class with a name that already exists for a module. For example the following file :

```
class Test
end
```

Will raise :
 `<top (required)>': Test is not a class (TypeError)`

Because Test is implicitely a module.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error of `<top (required)>` when I was doing the tutorial in the book "Jump Start Sinatra."

I got rid of the error by making sure that I ran `sudo gem install <GEM_IN_YOUR_FILE>`. So in my case I had a `main.rb` and in that file I had this

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra-contrib'
```

So I went back into the root of my project and ran `sudo gem install sinatra` and `sudo gem install sinatra-contrib` and then my project worked fine.

Your errors will vary, but because this is what I found when I searched on Google, I know others will come here for similar reasons. And I offer this solution to at least get you thinking in the right direction since this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Solved it by converting .rb files encoding to UTF-8-BOM using Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Ninto's answer makes total sense. It's a stack trace that you get one things fail. I was running my tests by doing:

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

and what I got was:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/foodie_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require 'foodie/food'

SyntaxError:
  /Users/honey/Dev/foodie/funnex/lib/funnex/food.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end
# ./lib/foodie.rb:4:in `require'
# ./lib/foodie.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/foodie_spec.rb:1:in `require'
# ./spec/foodie_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00002 seconds (files took 0.07998 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

All I was doing wrong in my case was that I was missing and `end`.

But to understand the stack trace more, start from bottom of the commented out lines ie this line:

```
# ./spec/foodie_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

- At line 1 of `foodie_spec` I had `require 'foodie'`
- At line 4 of `foodie.rb` I had `require 'foodie/food'`
- I errored out at line 17 of `foodie/food`

Stack traces in Ruby are also [named](https://medium.com/@nerdplusdog/how-to-read-and-resolve-common-error-codes-in-ruby-9a3ae4bfb0db) backtraces or stack traceback