# What does mean <top (required)> in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails

I have some rspec test. For example

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do

  before (:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in @user
  end

  describe "GET 'show'" do

    it "should be successful" do
      get :show, :id => @user.id
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should find the right user" do
      get :show, :id => @user.id
      assigns(:user).should == @user
    end

  end

end
```

When I run the rspec i get some errors

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController GET 'show' should be successful
     Failure/Error: @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       SQLite3::SQLException: near "SAVEPOINT": syntax error: SAVEPOINT active_record_1
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UsersController GET 'show' should find the right user
     Failure/Error: @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       SQLite3::SQLException: near "SAVEPOINT": syntax error: SAVEPOINT active_record_1
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:12 # UsersController GET 'show' should be successful
rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:17 # UsersController GET 'show' should find the right user
```

What does the  mean and what could be the problem with that rspec?

Comment: Check out this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330657/what-does-top-required-mean-in-a-ruby-stack-trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host is CentOS5 and the included SQLite version is old and dont work with the sqlite3 gem.
So i had to config the bundler to use a newer installed sqlite version.

```
bundle config build.sqlite3 \
  --with-sqlite3-include=/package/host/localhost/sqlite-3/include \
  --with-sqlite3-lib=/package/host/localhost/sqlite-3/lib
```

Followed by a `bundle install`

Problem solved.