# rspec <top(required)> error - no other good information - what is the root cause?

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails, spork

Here is my setup:

rails 3.12.2, rspec 2.13.1, spork 0.9.2, mysql gem 0.3.11.  I am new to RoR and rspec.

I run spork in the background with no issues reported in spork.

When I run my model tests with:

`rake spec:models --trace`

I get the following results:

```
 Invoke spec:models (first_time)
 Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
 Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
 Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
 Invoke environment (first_time)
 Execute environment
 Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
 Execute db:load_config
 Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
 Execute db:test:prepare
 Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
 Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
 Invoke environment
 Invoke db:load_config
 Execute db:test:purge
 Execute db:test:load
 Invoke db:test:load_schema (first_time)
 Invoke db:test:purge
 Execute db:test:load_schema
 Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
 Invoke environment
 Invoke db:load_config
 Execute db:schema:load
 Execute test:prepare
 Execute spec:models
 ruby.exe -S rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb
 ..

  Finished in 0.51565 seconds
  2 examples, *0 failures*

  Randomized with seed 540

<-- Slave(1) run done!
**rake aborted!**
ruby.exe -S rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb     **failed**
/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:156:in `run_task'
/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'

....

/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `**<top (required)>**'
bin/rake:19:in `load'
bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => spec:models
```

So my tests seem to pass but the overall rspec results fail.  If I run this **without** spork it works just fine.   So my (revised) question is how do I get this to work with spork?  Is there something I need to configure for spork to address the issue I am seeing?  Below is both the rspec and spork files.

Here is the rspec for "user":

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'
require_relative '../../app/models/user'

describe User do

before :each do
    @user = User.new login: 'TestUser', name: 'Test User 999'
end


it "login and name are required fields" do
  @user.name.should_not be_nil
  @user.login.should_not be_nil
end

it "can be instantiated" do
  User.new.should be_an_instance_of(User)
end
end
```

Here is the spec_helper.rb contents:

```
require 'spork'
Spork.prefork do

# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|


  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true 
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false


  config.order = "random"
  end
 end

Spork.each_run do
 # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end
```

So what is the root cause of the "top required" error above when running with spork?   Have I provided all that is needed to determine the root cause?

I have looked at other questions ([What does mean <top (required)> in rspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288566/what-does-mean-top-required-in-rspec)) ([What does "<top (required)>" mean in a Ruby stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330657/what-does-top-required-mean-in-a-ruby-stack-trace)) but they are not the same issue.

TIA,

Scott

Comment: What happens if you run the same command without a running spork server?

Comment: Running with spork causes the issue.  That is if I run without spork it works!   I will edit my question to how to get spork to work then. :)

Comment: revised my question to ask why test fail with spork but don't fail if spork is not running. I added the rspec helper ruby code too.