# Problems with require in gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I am trying to make a simple gem which has some modules. However, after I have built and installed the gem and try require it in a script I get an error:

```
from ...ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- my_gem/some_class (LoadError)
```

And

```
from ...ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/my_gem-0.0.1/lib/my_gem.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

Line 2 in `my_gem.rb` is `require "my_gem/some_class`.

As far as I understand ([from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330657/what-does-top-required-mean-in-a-ruby-stack-trace)) the problem seems to be that the file I require isn't found.

What is going on? Why can't I require my own files inside the gem?

---

The files I want to require is "next to" the version.rb.

```
#File Structure
#
# root
#   |->lib
#   |   |->my_gem.rb
#   |   |->my_gem
#   |   |    |->some_class.rb
#   |   |    |->some_class2.rb
#   |   |    |->version.rb
```

The SomeClass looks like this:

```
module MyGem
    class SomeClass
        def self.someMethod
        ...
    end
end
```

All I do in the script where I get the error is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require "rubygems"
require "my_gem"
```

---

Gemspec:

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'my_gem/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "my_gem"
  spec.version       = MyGem::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["My Name"]
  spec.email         = ["my_email@gmail.com"]
  spec.description   = %q{A simple Ruby gem that fails.}
  spec.summary       = %q{Failing gem for Ruby.}
  spec.homepage      = "http://some.website.com"
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.3"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake"
end
```

Comment: Whether the files are found or not depends on their path. Please edit your question to include the filenames and folder names (relative to the project root) of the calling file and the file you want to `require`.

Comment: Would you also provide us with your `Gemspec`: are you sure you have all the files included?

Comment: There we go. Directory structure and gemspec. Maybe I am doing something wrong in the gemspec

Comment: Run `git ls-files` from console and post the result as well, please. Did you add all your class files to git, didn’t you?

Comment: Well, explicit word. I did not know you needed to commit stuff to git for the gem to build. Why this design decision? What if I want to use something other than git for versioning? (by the way. Feel free to add as answer)

Comment: You specify in the `Gemspec` that you want to use all the files that are under git versioning control. If you don't want that, enter something else at `spec.files`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have not added your class files to `git`, while your `Gemspec` file uses common pattern to specify files to be added to `gem`:

```
spec.files = `git ls-files`.split($/)
```

You have two options not to run into same trouble again:

- Add all the files to version control before building a gem;
- Use hand-written `spec.files` list in `Gemspec`.

Or, if you are using `svn`, you might want to change the `spec.files` to:

```
spec.files = `svn list`.split($/)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Was unaware that the gemspec was using this git command to dynamically add the files to the gem. However, could not this be done nicer with the `Dir` command?

Comment: Uhmm… The very pattern of coding nowadays is likely to keep all the needed stuff under version control. `Git` is likely the most popular one around. With this approach you may create some garbage/temporary stuff within your working directory, not worrying about it will be packed within your `gem`. Clean repository ⇒ clean gem.

Comment: Plus you might want to produce two/three/N gems from one directory tree (subfolders etc.) So these will be N different repositories, producing N clear gems, despite all the code is stored within one top folder.

Comment: Well, it would be fine if the gem used the version of the file within the git repo, but it only lists the files that are present in the repo. Thus all changes you do to the gem is still going to be in the gem, even though they are not versioned into the gem. So in my mind this is not a very good practice. There might be other aspects I am unaware of though.