# Getting <NoMethodError (undefined method `charset=` for > when submitting contact form through sendgrid

Tags: ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-5, sendgrid

I've recently graduated from a bootcamp so I'm still trying to wrap my head around things.

I'm trying to implement a contact form on my rails app which I've used the mail_form gem together with sendgrid.  I believe I've set the SMTP correctly.  But when i try to submit the form i get this error:

```
2020-05-01T21:23:04.573941+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-05-01T21:23:04.573868 #4]  INFO -- : [268934ad-22d8-4836-b22a-3f130941a309]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"==auth==", "contact"=>{"email"=>"customer@gmail.com", "name"=>"josejose", "message"=>"jose here, first mesage"}, "commit"=>"Enviar Mensaje"}
2020-05-01T21:23:04.584676+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2020-05-01T21:23:04.584577 #4] DEBUG -- : [268934ad-22d8-4836-b22a-3f130941a309] MailForm::Notifier#contact: processed outbound mail in 3.1ms
2020-05-01T21:23:04.585021+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-05-01T21:23:04.584935 #4]  INFO -- : [268934ad-22d8-4836-b22a-3f130941a309] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2020-05-01T21:23:04.586063+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-05-01T21:23:04.585975 #4] FATAL -- : [268934ad-22d8-4836-b22a-3f130941a309]
2020-05-01T21:23:04.586210+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-05-01T21:23:04.586127 #4] FATAL -- : [268934ad-22d8-4836-b22a-3f130941a309] NoMethodError (undefined method `charset=' for #<SendGrid::Mail:0x00007f61a50f42c8>):
2020-05-01T21:23:04.586292+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-05-01T21:23:04.586221 #4] FATAL -- : [268934ad-22d8-4836-b22a-3f130941a309]
2020-05-01T21:23:04.586378+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-05-01T21:23:04.586314 #4] FATAL -- : [268934ad-22d8-4836-b22a-3f130941a309] app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:12:in `create'
2020-05-01T21:23:04.587648+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/contacts" host=www.centraldehierros.com request_id=268934ad-22d8-4836-b22a-3f130941a309 fwd="80.4.60.53" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=http
```

I've followed the mail_form gem guide on github and used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIoORYeBdhs) as my guide for setting it up with sendgrid.

in my contact.rb file i have

```
 attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  # attribute :file,      :attachment => true

  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

  def headers
    {
      :subject => "My Contact Form",
      :to => "contact@app.com",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
```

## contacts controller

```
 def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.deliver
        format.html { redirect_to new_contact_path, alert: 'Your message was sent successfully. 
          We will get back to you shortly.' }
        flash.now[:error] = nil
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message'
      end
    end
  end
```

SMTP settings in #config/environment/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "http://www.app.com" }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method     = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings= {
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => '465',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain => 'http://www.app.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

I have also set all my necessary configs in my .env

I've tried searching through the internet and stack but couldn't find anything that's related to this error.

Currently using rails 5.2.1, ruby 2.6.5

Comment: Please include your full stack trace, not just the single line. The full stack trace will tell us what actually triggered this method call.

Comment: @anothermh, is a full trace the error log in the terminal? I've just updated it with the full error message.

Comment: This question includes an example of a stack trace: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6330657/3784008